How to enable source map in server-side code of production server to make log more readable in Sveltekit
I am developing my application using SvelteKit 2.0 with the JavaScript language.
On the development server, the source code appears to be enabled by default, enabling me to pinpoint the exact line numbers of errors in both the browser and server logs. I wish to achieve the same level of accuracy in the server logs for the production server, while ensuring that the browser cannot view my source code.
I tried the following configuration, but it didn't work as my expect on the production server. Also, I checked the internet and don't understand what sourcemap: 'hidden' exactly means and how doese it works?
vite.config.js
export default defineConfig(({ command, mode, isSsrBuild, isPreview }) => {
    return {
        ...
        build: {
            sourcemap: 'hidden'
        }
    };
});


I have researched extensively, but I still do not understand source maps and their workings, nor do I know how to proceed.
